# Linq query comparing dates - convert string column

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem with the linq query. I have in the database a column with a date, unfortunately, of the string type. I try to compare dates with a linq query.
Unfortunately, I do not know how to convert the value of p.Dates to the format datatime "yyyy-MM-dd"

```csharp
 int count_month_po = (from p in repozytorium.GetTable<OB_Zap>()
                                       where p.ID_inwest == dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() && (p.Dates > myDate)
                                       select p).Count();
```

Comment: Don't store date as a string, this is why, change your database type and make your life easier

Comment: Have you tried `Convert.ToDateTime(p.Dates)`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thx works perfectly !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` to parse it to `DateTime`before comparing it:

```
int count_month_po = (from p in repozytorium.GetTable<OB_Zap>()
                                       where p.ID_inwest == 
dgvData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() && (DateTime.ParseExact(p.Dates,"yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > myDate)
                                       select p).Count();
```

Comment: When I run this i havemessage: $exception {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}

Comment: you can use `DbFunctions` for this: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx)